# Computability text emphasizing the arithmetical point of view?

Tags: reference-request, logic, computability

I learned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_set#Properties) that

> A set is *recursively enumerable* if and only if it is at level
>   $\Sigma^0_1$ of the arithmetical hierarchy.

Is there an introductory text in computability theory that takes this as the definition of recursively enumerable, or at least emphasizes this (very elegant) characterization?

Comment: Most intro texts emphasize this equivalence heavily. However, the reason for taking the notion of r.e. as prior to $\Sigma_1^0$ (as opposed to merely defined by it) is that r.e. corresponds to the intuitive notion being able to *list out elements one at a time*, whereas $\Sigma_1^0$ corresponds to a certain syntactic characterization. The fact that these two are equivalent, of course, is important, but this should remain an important *equivalence* that can be proven, not as a *definition* that is taken for granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every nontrivial recursion theory book will prove that fact, which is just one part of Post's theorem. Rather than just saying that an r.e. set is $\Sigma^0_1$, in later proofs they will often use the fact that they can specify the formula; a set $A$ is r.e. if and only if there is an $e$ such that, for all $n$, $n \in A$ if and only if $\phi_e(n)$ halts. The formula "$\phi_e(n)$ halts" is $\Sigma^0_1$ by Kleene's normal form theorem.

Computability theorists will automatically think "$\Sigma^0_1$" when they see "$\phi_e(n)$ halts", but it's such a routine fact that it's not always worth mentioning. Conversely, our intuitive understanding of $\Sigma^0_1$ formulas is increased because we know they give r.e. sets.